# Esconder/Exibir uma div

Tags: javascript, html, div

Boa noite, gente.

Meu problema é esconder/mostrar uma div. Estou ainda estudando e treinando e não consegui resolver esse problema.

Possuo  o seguinte código html:

```
        <div class="celulares">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="celular">CELULAR</td>
                    <td id="fones">FONES</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <div id="celulares">
            <div class="boxy">
                <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/celulares/z-flip.png">
                <h1> Samsung Galaxy Z Flip </h1>
                <h3>R$ 6.731.34</h3>
                <p> ou 12x de 603,17 sem juros </p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="boxy">
                <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/celulares/motorola-moto-g8.png">
                <h1> Motorola Moto G8 </h1>
                <h3>R$ 1.282.47</h3>
                <p> ou 10x de 137,90 sem juros </p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="boxy">
                <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/celulares/s20.png">
                <h1> Samsung Galaxy S20 </h1>
                <h3>R$ 5.199.00</h3>
                <p> ou 12x de 433.25 sem juros </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="boxy">
                <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/celulares/iPhone-XR-Apple.png">
                <h1> iPhone XR Apple </h1>
                <h3>R$ 3.399.00</h3>
                <p> ou 10x de 399,90 sem juros </p>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div  id="foness">

            <div class="boxy">
            <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/fones/Bluetooth-JBL-T500BT.png">
            <h1> Fone Bluetooth JBL<br> T500BT </h1>
            <h3>R$ 223.45</h3>
            <p> ou 3x de 74.48  </p>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="boxy">
            <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/fones/JBL-Endurance-Run.png">
            <h1>  JBL-Endurance-Run </h1>
            <h3>R$ 108.00</h3>
            <p> ou 10x de 10,80  </p>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="boxy">
            <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/fones/Philips-Preto-Shl5005.png">
            <h1> Philips-Preto-Shl5005</h1>
            <h3>R$ 179,00</h3>
            <p> ou 12x de 14.91 </p>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="boxy">
            <a href="#"><img src = "imagens/fones/Xiaomi-Redmi-Airdots-Earbuds.png">
            <h1> Xiaomi-Redmi-Airdots-Earbuds</h1>
            <h3>R$ 3.399.00</h3>
            <p> ou 10x de 399,90 </p>
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

E meu JS:

```
    <script>
        var celulares;
        var foness;

        

        window.onload = function() {
            celulares = document.getElementById("celulares");
            foness = document.getElementById("foness");

            var celular = document.getElementById("celular");
            celular.onclick = mostrarcelulares;

            

            var fones = document.getElementById("fones");
            fones.onclick = mostrarfoness;

            celulares.classList.add("escondido");
            foness.classList.add("escondido");
    
        }

        function mostrarcelulares() {
            celular.classList.remove("escondido");
            foness.classList.add("escondido");

        }

        function mostrarfoness() {
            celulares.classList.add("escondido");

            foness.classList.remove("escondido");
            

        }

    </script>
```

Ambos estão se sobrescrevendo. Em um determinado momento estava funcionando, mas quando coloquei esse "boxy" parou completamente.

Observação:

O "escondido" está como display none no css

Answer (score 1):

Na chamada de um está `celular.classList` e noutro `celulares.classList`, uma pequena confusão nas variaveis..

```
function mostrarcelulares() {
    // celular.classList.remove("escondido");
    celulares.classList.remove("escondido");
    foness.classList.add("escondido");
}
```

Você também pode usar o [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) recebido pelo this, e resumir em uma função mais generica já que as duas fazem o mesmo, ex:

```
celular.onclick = alternarVisualizacao;
fones.onclick = alternarVisualizacao;
function alternarVisualizacao(event) {
    if (event.target === celular) {
        celulares.classList.remove("escondido")
        foness.classList.add("escondido")
    } else {
        foness.classList.remove("escondido")
        celulares.classList.add("escondido")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi, você está adicionando a classe escondido duas vezes. Por exemplo: assim que a página carrega no `window.onload` vc adiciona a classe "escondido" tanto na div `#celulares` quanto na div `#foness`. Depois, quando você clica no title de celular por exemplo, ele remove a classe de celular, mas adiciona novamente à div `#foness` que já possui. Esse comportamento pode estar gerando um efeito colateral. Seria bom você fazer uma verificação se a classe existe no elemento antes de adicionar ou removê-la.

Comment: Oi Gabriel! Podes clicar em [edit] e melhorar a resposta talvez com um exemplo?